# Deploying Spring MVC from SBT

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I'm having trouble deploying my Spring MVC Webapp with the xsbt-web-plugin. When i'm using container:start everything works just fine, but when i'm trying to run the packaged .war file inside a tomcat instance the webapp isn't loaded. It is just starting a plain tomcat instance.

Comment: Have you configured the context path in Tomcat?  By default, the *.war* filename is used for the context path, so deploying *my-webapp.war* would be accessible at *http://localhost:8080/my-webapp/*

Comment: @earldouglas yes i tried that. The problem is, that the servlet isn't detected at all when deployed, although it runs fine from sbt shell.

Answer (score 1):

I had an error in my path that slipped through. I've overlooked this for days. Sorry.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  Consider documenting in this answer both what you found and how you fixed it.  This will help in case other folks ever run into the same issue.